# swing accelerators

Tags: java, swing

I read the difference about mnemonics and accelerators but now I was wondering if these
accelerators are used only with menu items or also on other JComponents.

Answer (score 5):

You can use key bindings for any JComponent :)

Check out this [guide](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html)

Comment: +1 Also a good reason to consider `Action`: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html